# a few questions for x86 assembly: AccessViolationException, pointer arithmetic, and string comparison

Tags: assembly, x86, access-violation, string-comparison, pointer-arithmetic

Before I ask any questions I know the best advice is to learn how to use the debugger, only problem is I'm not sure how to get it running on Visual Studio 2013 in a virtual machine on my mac. Both me and my professor struggled to get it running, so debugging isn't an option for me at the moment.

Program specification:
int l_search (char* list, int count, char* token)

list - the starting address of the list of structures to be searched. Structure holds a int of a Student's ID, followed by a char array of 20 elements for the Student's name

count - total number of names in the list

token - name to be searched or in the list

This function returns the student ID of the student record in the list. While the list was constructed, the ID was populated in sequence starting with 1). If the name is not found, then it returns 0. When it returns 0, print a message on the console. No partial searching, must be all or nothing.

So here's my attempt at this in assembly:

```
xor eax, eax                        ; zero out the `enter code here`result, eax
xor ebx, ebx                        ; zero out a counter, ebx
xor edx, edx                        ; zero out a token modifier, edx
mov esi, list                       ; move the list pointer to esi
mov edi, token                      ; move the token pointer to edi
mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi]               ; move the first char to dl

LOWERCASE_TOKEN :

or dl, 0x20                         ; lowercase the char
mov BYTE PTR[edi], dl               ; set the char in token to lowercase
//mov BYTE PTR[edi + ebx], dl       ;
add ebx, 1                          ; increment counter
add edi, 1                          ; move token pointer to the next char
//mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi + ebx]       ; set the next char to dl
mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi]               ; move the next char into dl
cmp dl, 0                           ; check if token pointer is the null terminator
jnz LOWERCASE_TOKEN                 ; if not keep lowercasing the token
sub edi, ebx                        ; move the token pointer back to the first char
mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi]               ; ACCESSVIOLATIONEXCEPTION
xor ebx, ebx                        ; reset ebx
mov ecx, count                      ; set the counter for the loop

SEARCH :

mov eax, DWORD PTR[esi]             ; move the STUDENT ID to the result, eax
mov bl, BYTE PTR[esi + 4]           ; move the first char of the line being checked to bl
//add esi, 4                        ; move the list pointer to the first char
//mov bl, BYTE PTR[esi]             ; set bl to the first char of line being checked    
push ecx                            ; push the counter onto the stack
mov ecx, 1                          ; set ecx to be a line counter
//xor ecx, ecx                      ; zero out ecx

CHECK_LINE :
or bl, 0x20                         ; lowercase the char in the line being observed
cmp bl, dl                          ; check if the two char are equivalent
jne NEXT_LINE                       ; if not equal move to the next line
//add edi, 1                        ; move token pointer to the next char
//cmp BYTE PTR[edi], 0              ; check if next char in token pointer is the null terminator
cmp BYTE PTR[edi + ecx], 0          ; check if next byte in token pointer is the null terminator
jz DONE                             ; if so, finished searching
mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi + ecx]         ; move the next char in token to dl
//mov dl, BYTE PTR[edi]             ; move the next char in token to dl
mov bl, BYTE PTR[esi + ecx + 4]     ; move the next char in line being checked to bl
//add esi, 1                        ; move the list pointer to the next char
//mov bl, BYTE PTR [esi]            ; set bl to the next char
add ecx, 1                          ; increment the line counter
jmp CHECK_LINE                      ; continue checking line for equivalency

NEXT_LINE :
//sub esi, 4
//sub esi, ecx
//sub edi, ecx
add esi, 24                         ; move the list pointer to the next line
pop ecx                             ; pop loop counter back to ecx to maintain loop stability
LOOP SEARCH                         ; keep searching

DONE :
```

Q1: AccessViolationException

I indicated which line I get the AccessViolationException on, which is when I attempt to move the first char of the token back into dl right after I attempted to move the pointer back. Why does this happen?

Q2: pointer arithmetic & string comparison

I've tried different ways of moving the pointer when I'm iterating through a string of chars, which is why I have certain lines commented out. I know for sure that my LOWERCASE_TOKEN correctly lowercases the token in both ways from testing print statements, so I'm just not sure why when I actually start searching the list it's not correctly comparing. The list I'm given is:

Arturo Bryan chris David Jon Mark shane SIMON Thomas Tony

I've tested the search with different name's in the list and it always goes through the whole loop even when the token is one of the name's in the list and outputs a student ID of 10.

Am I not searching the list and comparing each element correctly??

Comment: If you can't get debugging to work in the VM, try using gdb outside your VM.  Assemble with `yasm`, link with `gcc -m32` (since I see you've written 32bit code, which will probably truncate addresses and fault if assembled as x86-64 code).  Or maybe you'll get lucky and someone will come along and do your debugging for you, if it wasn't an address-truncation problem.

Comment: We don't see how you defined `token` and `list` so we can't tell whether you are missing a level of indirection or not (ie. you might need `[token]`). If you are asking others to debug for you, you should provide full working code. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, while your way should work, a safer way to reset `edi` to the `token` is to just reload it instead of playing around with arithmetic.

Comment: Try using windbg instead of the visual studio debugger in your vm.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a different implementation that works:

```
xor eax, eax                ; zero out the result, eax
mov esi, list               ; move the list pointer to esi
mov edi, token              ; move the token pointer to edi
mov ecx, count              ; move the count to ecx
inc ecx                     ; increment the count for correct boundary test conditions

SEARCH:

xor ebx, ebx                ; a char counter
mov al, BYTE PTR[esi + 4]   ; move first char of a line to al
mov ah, BYTE PTR[edi]       ; move first char of token to ah
and al, 0xDF                ; uppercase the char
and ah, 0xDF                ; uppercase the char
cmp al, ah                  ; check if equal
jnz NEXT_LINE               ; if not move to next line

CHECK_LINE:

add ebx,1                   ; increment char counter
add esi,1                   ; move the list pointer to the next char
add edi,1                   ; move the token pointer to the next char
mov al, BYTE PTR[esi + 4]   ; move the list pointer char into al
mov ah, BYTE PTR[edi]       ; move the token pointer char into ah
and al, 0xDF                ; uppercase the char
and ah, 0xDF                ; uppercase the char
cmp al, ah                  ; check if equal
jnz NEXT_LINE               ; if not move to the next line
cmp al, 0x00                ; check for null terminator
jz NULL_CHECK               ; check for null terminator
jmp CHECK_LINE              ; keep searching line

NULL_CHECK:

cmp ah, 0x00                ; check if done
jz SUCCESSFUL_SEARCH        ; search completed

NEXT_LINE:

sub esi, ebx                ; move the list pointer back to the start of that line
cmp DWORD PTR[esi + 24], ecx; check if the end of the list has been reached
jz FAILED_SEARCH            ; if so token is not in list and search has failed
mov edi, token              ; reset the token pointer
add esi, 24                 ; move list pointer to the next line
jmp SEARCH                  ; continue searching the list

FAILED_SEARCH:

xor eax, eax                ; failed search, token not in list
jmp DONE                    ; end program

SUCCESSFUL_SEARCH:

sub esi, ebx                ; move list pointer to the beggining successful line
mov eax, DWORD PTR[esi]     ; place the students ID into the result
```